# F# 'function' functions cannot inline

Tags: f#

The following 2 functions

```
let episodeDict1 (a: obj) = 
    match a with
    | :? (Episode -> _) as generator ->
        let episodes = [D; W; M]
        let values = episodes |> List.map generator
        List.zip episodes values
    | :? _ as value -> [D, value; W, value; M, value]
    |> dict |> Dictionary


let episodeDict2: obj -> Dictionary<Episode, _> = function
    | :? (Episode -> _) as generator ->
        let episodes = [D; W; M]
        let values = episodes |> List.map generator
        List.zip episodes values |> dict |> Dictionary
    | :? _ as value -> [D, value; W, value; M, value] |> dict |> Dictionary
```

do the same thing, however the second cannot be marked inline

> let inline episodeDict2...
>
> FS0832    Only functions may be marked 'inline'

Which seems really weird.

**Can someone explain?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, the two functions are really equivalent and so the compiler could be smarter and figure this out. However, the problem is that the second function is defined as a "value" that is not "syntactic function", i.e., it is not defined as `let func x y z = ...`. The compiler uses a simple rule and only allows inlinding of syntactic functions.

The reason for this is that, when you have a function that is not defined as a syntactic function, it may not be possible to inline it. For example:

```
let foo = 
  let mutable counter = 0
  fun () -> counter <- counter + 1; counter
```

If you took the body of this definition and placed it into the place where the function is used, it would change the meaning of the program! For example `foo () + foo ()` returns `3`, but if you did the inlining naively:

```
( let mutable counter = 0
  fun () -> counter <- counter + 1; counter ) () + 
( let mutable counter = 0
  fun () -> counter <- counter + 1; counter ) ()
```

You would get `2` as the result! Again, you could imagine more clever compiler dealing with this - but I believe the F# decision here is reasonable - have a simple rule that is easy to understand (and ensures you get the right thing).